# SpriteKit bodyInRect finding node when it shouldn't

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm attempting to detect if there's a sprite node immediately to the left or right of the current sprite node.

This seems straightforward, but I'm seeing an odd behaviour.

I've created a thin rect (width = 1point) that's the same height as the current node and with the same origin as the current node.

e.g:

```
// Create a thin rect that's aligned to the left edge of 'block' 
CGRect adjacentFrame;
adjacentFrame = CGRectMake(block.frame.origin.x,
                           block.frame.origin.y,
                           1,
                           block.frame.size.height);

// Shift the rect left a few points to position it to the left of 'block'
adjacentFrame.origin.x -= 10;
```

Then I test to see if that rect (adjacentFrame) is intersecting a node:

```
SKPhysicsBody* obstructingBody;
obstructingBody = [self.physicsWorld bodyInRect:adjacentFrame];
```

Now, the weird thing is, obstructingBody contains 'block' itself!

I've even added code to add a SpriteNode to the scene with a frame of adjacentFrame so I can check the rect's positioning.  It's clearly displaying a few points left of 'block' and is clearly not touching it!

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

bodyInRect needs scene coordinates. You provide coordinates in the coordinate space of block.parent. Unless block.parent is the scene itself, you need to convert origin with:

```
CGRect blockFrame = block.frame;
blockFrame.origin = [self convertPoint:blockFrame.origin toNode:self.scene];
```

Also block's width must be less than 10 otherwise your -10 offset isn't enough to move the frame outside the block's frame.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  block.Parent is indeed the scene itself, so that would seem ok.  To test, I've added a sprite to the scene at the rect I'm using in the call to bodyInRect so I can visually see the area that's being tested.  The test sprite draws on-screen outside of 'block's position, so I can't see why it would be returning 'block' itself...